# NSMutableArray auto updates with Dictionary in singleton

Tags: ios, singleton, nsmutablearray

I have a weird problem. I have a singleton with dictionary in it. This dictionary is updated regularly in runtime. In a viewcontroller I access this singleton dictionary and create a new NSMutableArray.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

Initialized it in viewDidload:

```
_myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then in viewDidAppear, I assign the array to the singleton NSMutableDictionary *myDict values:

```
_myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[[DataCenter singleton] myDict] allValues]];
```

**Before doing anything to _myArray**, I monitor _myArray values in a timer and it seems that it always keep on changing following the singleton dictionary values.

Why and how to create an independent NSMutableArray that isn't somehow tied to this dictionary singleton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a weird problem, it's how Objective-C works.  Your singleton array is just a collection of object references.  You've filled `_myArray` with those exact same references.  All modifications in one will be reflected by the other because, well, they're the same objects.

In order to actually make new objects, you need to make a copy.  Something like this:

```
_myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[[DataCenter singleton] myDict] allValues] copyItems:YES];
```

**EDIT:**

I can't test with `[[[DataCenter singleton] myDict] allValues]` in my compiler, but a contrived example incase you want to experiment with deepCopy and array.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"foo"];
NSMutableArray* _myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:array copyItems:YES];
```

Comment: Got an error saying no visible interface for NSArray declares the selector copyItems:

Comment: Ok i think we have to use mutableCopy instead of copyItems:YES. Anyway accepting your answer once you modify to correct code. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I had a wrong bit of syntax in there, but as far as my understanding goes, mutableCopy only creates a shallow copy whereas copyItems creates a deep copy, which I believe is what you want.

Comment: I tried with mutableCopy seems to work. copyItems:YES is method of NSDictionary object. Not NSArray (which [dict allValues] return). Hence the error.

Comment: Ah no wonder it gave me error. copyItems is method of initwithArray. Problem is I don't want to init the array here.

Comment: Basically, I want the init to remain in viewDidload. And in viewDidAppear i load up the array with arrayWithArray: mutableCopy.

Comment: Anyway thank you for the explanation it directed me to the solution.

Comment: Ah ha.  I was curious, so thanks for explaining.  Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy that object as below :

```
_myArray =[[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[[DataCenter singleton] myDict] allValues]]mutableCopy];
```